# Convert Swagger JSON to RAML/YAML

Tags: json, yaml, swagger, raml

How do I convert Swagger JSON to RAML/YAML and validate it?  I am not looking for a programmatic way, just a one off conversion.

Comment: this one too https://github.com/essuraj/swagger-toolbox - https://swagger-toolbox.firebaseapp.com/

Answer (score 56):

Here are the steps:

1. Export Swagger JSON into a file on your drive. This JSON should be published on your server at the following URI: /swagger/docs/v1
2. Go to http://editor.swagger.io/#/
3. On the top left corner, select File-> Import File... Point to the local Swagger JSON file you exported in step #1 to open in the Swagger Editor
4. Select Generate Client -> Swagger YAML option from the menu
5. It will generate the YAML that you can validate at http://www.yamllint.com/ site

Comment: I don't think that's what the question was about, this generates Swagger YAML, not RAML YAML.

Comment: This does not answer the question but the actual solution can be found using almost the same way - Find my answer below.

Answer (score 9):

Its actually pretty simple

Web version of [swagger editor](http://editor.swagger.io/#/) gives the flexibility to import your existing swagger file(JSON/YAML) and download the configuration file that is currently being shown. So just combine these two.

> Note: Converting JSON to YAML exists, but not JSON to RAML

1. First import your swagger JSON at http://editor.swagger.io/#/ **(File > Import File)**
2. Once you see your configurations, just download the corresponding YAML version **(File > Download YAML)**.

The YAML version of the JSON you just uploaded will be downloaded.

Answer (score 6):

To convert API spec between various formats (e.g. Swagger/OpenAPI, RAML, Postman, etc), you can use the following free and open source tools:

- https://github.com/lucybot/api-spec-converter
- https://github.com/stoplightio/api-spec-converter

Answer (score 4):

Conversion

If you are looking to convert from any version Swagger to RAML 0.8 then APITransformer.com can do it for you. We're almost done with RAML 1.0 export. Will release it in a week's time.

Validation

The converted description comes out of the same code-gen engine that APIMatic uses to validate an API description before generating SDKs/Client libraries. Therefore, the converted RAML will be validated by default.

API descriptions in a variety of formats can also be validated via [APIMatic's CLI](https://github.com/apimatic/apimatic-cli) or [APIMatic's API](https://docs.apimatic.io/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same OpenAPI spec (say for example same version 3.0.1) in a json format and you want to convert it to a YAML format, you only need to use `yq` the following way:

```
yq -p json -o yaml file.json > converted_file.yaml
```

And vice versa:

```
yq -p yaml -o json file.yaml > converted_file.json
```

`-p:` input format type

`-o:` output format type

Note that JSON is a subset of YAML

Answer (score 0):

While I wish there was a command line tool, this company has made a converter it seems:

https://apitransformer.com/

Comment: There is a command line tool for conversions as well. Its located at https://github.com/apimatic/apimatic-cli

Comment: The link https://apimatic.io/transformer actually works and doing the same with their apimatic-cli seems to be tricky. Would you have an out-of-the-box guide?