# Is there any tool available to convert OAS 3.0 to OAS 2.0 or RAML?

Tags: openapi, raml

I have a UI that generates OAS 3.0 json and my api manager supports OAS 2.0. Is there anyway to convert OAS 3.0 to OAS 2.0? I do not have control over UI so I have to take the JSON as it is and convert to OAS 2.0 version or RAML 2.0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert OpenAPI 3.0 to Swagger 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56637299/convert-openapi-3-0-to-swagger-2-0), [Convert Swagger JSON to RAML/YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32730224/113116)